# MySQL export / import error — user denied + acces denied

Tags: mysql, import, export

I am trying to do a pretty standard procedure; exporting a databse from one server to another. (I maybe should inform you, that it is 2 different webhosting hotels, but it should be the same kind of database; MySql)

The export goes fine, without any problems.

But when i do the import, it says

```
#1142 - CREATE command denied to user '*******'@'*******' for table 'ide_commentmeta"
```

Then i did some research — and i found some solutions, here on Stack Overflow, that brought me a step further — making that user and granting priviliges to that. But that gave me this error:

```
"#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation"
```

Can anyone tell me how to make the most smoothest expot / import of a MySQL database, where the user and database name and password are different?

Thanx in advance.

// Brokop

Comment: You know you shouldn't be posting credentials here, right? Some brute-force attack and your db is... puff!.. gone :)

Comment: Hi Alex

Whoops. Thanks. Rookie mistake :)

Any advice on how to make the operation work?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. It pipes the dump through ssh to the new server:

```
mysqldump -uU1 -pP1 dbname | ssh LU@serverName "mysql -uU2 -pP2 -D targetDbName"
```

Where:
`U1` is your exporting user
`P1` is the corresponding password
`LU` is the linux username for 'serverName'
`serverName` is your target server (either IP, hostname...)
`U2` is the importing user
`P2` is the corresponding password

Note:
1) I'm assuming you can set publicKey authentication to `serverName`.
2) U1 has full export rights for the `dbname` database
3) U2 has root-like permissions to import the database

Hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: Thanks Alex. 

Where in the sql-file do i put this line of code?

Should i put your line of code in starting from scratch or after i have progressed the user and granting proces?

Comment: You need to run this from a terminal on your source server (note: from there you need to be able to `ssh` to your target server). It's not a line you can append to an sql file. This line *does* the actual export and import.